# Showing the set defined as $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x \text{ not an integer}\}$ is open.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that if $S =  \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \notin \mathbb{Z}\}$, then $S$ is open.

My approach was to realize that this can be rewritten as $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid k < x < k + 1\}$ for all $k$ in he integers.

Let $p \in s$ such that $p = (p_x, p_y)$ and $p_x \notin \mathbb{Z}$. More importantly $p_x$ is in $k < x < k + 1$ for an arbitrary integer $k$.

Define an open ball $B(r, p)$ such that $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^2 : d(y,p) < r\}$.

Now let $q \in B(r,p)$, ie: $d(q,p) < r$.

NEED TO SHOW: $q \in S$.

I proceed by triangle inequality.

$$|q_x - p_x| \leq \|q - p\| \lt r$$

$$-r \lt q_x - p_x \lt r$$

$$-r + p_x \lt q_x \lt r + p_x$$

So I've reached the stage where I need to pick an $r$, but I can't figure out how to determine what $r$ to pick (without just guessing) so I can get rid of the $px$'s and get involved a $k$. Is this even the correct approach? Perhaps, I thought, I should use the fact that I know $k < p_x < k + 1$? But I couldn't figure out how either. I also should be keeping in mind that this new $r$ should be a smaller "value", correct?

In a general situation, what's the best strategy (algebraic or otherwise) for determining your radius $r$?

EDIT: So I used the fact that it looks like $p_x - r = k$ and $p_x + r = k + 1$ but I have no rigorous way of showing this. If I can do this I can simply bring it into my inequality. How can I better show this?

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture of $S$ (actually it is easier to draw its complement, $\mathbb{R}^2 \smallsetminus S$). You should see a bunch of vertical lines, one for each integer. Pick any point $(x,y)$ in $S$. What's the biggest ball centered on this point that you can draw, that is contained in $S$ (i.e. doesn't cross any lines)? What is its radius? (Hint: Label the lines corresponding to $k$ and $k+1$. The radius depends on which line it is closest to.)

Comment: I already drew this picture :) Hence why I already came up with k < p_x < k + 1. However I see what you mean, the radius is te distance from p_x to k, which is just r = k - p_x?

Comment: (1) The radius must be positive. (2) What if $x = 1.7$?

Comment: Then the radius is 0.3?

Comment: Right, but how can you generalize it?

Comment: Well the radius if we're centered half way with equal distance on both sides can be  r = (k+1) - p_x or r = p_x - k (edited).

Comment: Still stuck :/ Any help? I can't figure out how to use this in my overall work.

Comment: I think I got it. k = - r + px and k + 1 = r + px.

Comment: Could someone confirm if I am on the right track? I am not sure how "bumps" work on here...